# How to use the plain name of the running (test) page in Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse

I'm currently exploring FitNesse/Slim as an automated test tool. Scenarios are defined on a page named Example.ScenarioLibrary, and this particular test is defined on Example.T002Scripts.

I've defined a recurring scenario, which creates a task in the System Under Test, that I want to use in many different tests. However, the task names need to be different. I tried to arrange that by including [`${RUNNING_PAGE_NAME}`](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.QuickReferenceGuide#GlobalVARIABLES) in the Slim table.

```
!2 Task configuration
|scenario        |create new task with duration           |duration                               |
|click           |New                                                                             |
|enter           |[TEST] ${RUNNING_PAGE_NAME} @{duration}s|as|Name                                |
```

This sort-of works, except that this produces the following Name: `[TEST] <a href="Example.T002Scripts">T002Scripts</a> 20s`. I want (and expected) it to be `[TEST] T002Scripts 20s` or `[TEST] Example.T002Scripts 20s` (both would be fine). Is there any way to get rid of that HTML markup? I've tried other variables (`${PAGE_NAME}`, `${PAGE_PATH}` and `${RUNNING_PAGE_PATH}`) but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution in one of the projects which came packaged with my FitNesse installation: [hsac-fitness-fixtures](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures). It contains some methods for string manipulation in the form of [StringFixture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/master/wiki/FitNesseRoot/HsacExamples/SlimTests/UtilityFixtures/StringFixtureTest.wiki). One of the methods is `replace all` which allows removing the HTML tags:

```
|$testName=|replace all                  |<[^>]*>|in|${RUNNING_PAGE_NAME}|with||
|enter     |[TEST] $testName @{duration}s|as     |Name                         |
```

The name of the task is now `[TEST] T002Scripts 20s` as desired.